# What are data available and data required in SSI/SPI

Tags: microcontroller, spi, serial

I'm trying to understand SSP/SPI but I'm stuck on the concept of **data available** and **data required**. Here's how it explains it in the textbook (Valvano's Introduction to ARM Microcontroller):

> The key to proper transmission is to select one edge of the clock to
> be used by the transmitter to change the output, and use the other
> edge to latch the data in the receiver. In this way data is latched
> during the time when it is stable. Data available is the time when the
> output data is actually valid, and data required is the time when the
> input data must be valid.

1. Well, if I transmit a data then the FIFO will push those the data bits to the shift register where the clock then pushes the bits out of or into the I/O. When I write data then *there is data*. If I don't write any data, then there is no data - what does it mean by **data available**? Or does it imply a control register to skip an element in the FIFO and make the data available or unavailable to read or write?
2. What is that Gaussian distribution arrow between S8 and S9. Is that some sort of probability that the data can be read properly? Hence the **validity** of data or some percentage of error?
3. *"...Data required is the time when the input data must be valid..."* So data required is a time? Data is being transmitted in Tx and clocked by Clk. What is **data required** and why is it a time?

[image: Synchronous serial timing showing the data available interval overlaps the data required inte]

Comment: I think you're getting misled. It's possibly simpler than you think. Data available is the period of time between S8 and S9 and the gaussian shaped arrow is nothing to do with a distribution gaussian or otherwise. The "R" (read) sits middle of the data symbol and is where the receiver optimally reads at this mid-point between S8 and S9. Data required is also called data set up period and is a time period where the data must be setup and stable before "T" occurs. It may extend a little after the "T" event but it certainly needs to be before "T".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation S5, S8, and S9 are times that are shown elsewhere in a table.

S5 looks like the Clock to output data transition time. There are both minimum and maximum times.

S8 is the data setup time for the receiver.

S9 is the data hold time for the receiver.

What you describe as a "Gaussian distribution arrow" are just arrows indicating the times S8 and S9 (S8 is before the clock edge, S9 is after).

The Data setup time is how long in advance of the clock edge the correct data state needs to be present. (probably needs to be a few nanoseconds).

The data hold time is how long after the clock edge the data needs to be held static to ensure the data is read correctly (could be zero).

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two completely different things. Writing data to the register makes it shift out, so there is data available for transmission. The data is shifted out by using the clock signal.

The devices must operate with the clock so that they have a chance to see stable data, i.e. if the master update the data on falling edge of the clock, the slave must load the data in on the rising edge of the clock.

The slave needs to have the data stable for some time before the clock edge, and the data must be stable some time after the clock edge, or the slave won't be able to capture it properly.

The master must then of course make sure that the data is available for long enough time before the clock edge to fulfill the requirement of the slave how much before clock edge it must be stable.